# Correct way to model has_many through style relationship in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I need to figure out how to model this best in mongoid, I have a galleries model and an images model.  I need to be able to have images be able to be referenced in multiple documents and I need each gallery to allow the images to be sortable within the gallery.  In mysql I would do this with a join table but I can't seem to figure out how best to do this with mongodb/mongoid.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`has_and_belongs_to_many`, you don't need a join table here. In mongoid HABTM stores array of ids on both sides. so if you define:

```
class Gallery; has_and_belongs_to_many :images; end
class Image; has_and_belongs_to_many : galleries; end
```

You will have `image_ids` in gallery documents and `gallery_ids` in image documents. Sorting images in a gallery is also possible, `gallery.images` is a relation proxy to which you can chain more conditions to filter/sort results:

```
gallery.images.desc(:updated_at)
gallery.images.asc(:user_id)
gallery.images.asc(:my_sort_order_from_drag_drop)
```

Comment: But in this case if I needed a separate sort order for each gallery (an image in 2 galleries needs to have separate sort numbers for each gallery) I dont think doing it this way will work.  I think I have to resort to a 3rd table, similar to a join table but I think I can get away with embedding the sort table in the gallery.

Comment: Yes, in that case embedding merge documents in gallery will be your best bet. You have to take care of not making n+1 queries for gallery images if you go that route.